# Equivalent definitions of a continuous function.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I want to show the following two definitions of a continuous function are equivalent and was wondering if my proof is valid. In particular, I felt that (2) -> (1) was much simpler than (1) -> (2). First, let $X$ and $Y$ be top. spaces with the function $f \colon X \to Y$.

**Definition 1.** If $U$ is open in $Y$ then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

**Definition 2.** Let $A \subset X$ and $p$ be a limit point of $A$. Then $f(p) \in \text{cl}({f(A)})$

(1) -> (2) If $p \in A$ then $f(p) \in f(A)$ so assume $p \notin A$. If $f(p) \in f(A)$ we are done so additionally assume $f(p) \notin f(A)$. Take $U$ to the be an open neighborhood of $f(p)$. Then by (1) $f^{-1}(U), $ is the open neighborhood of p. Since $p$ is a limit point of $A$, there is a point $q \in f^{-1}(U) \cap A$. Then $f(q) \in U \cap f(A)$. We assumed $f(p) \notin f(A)$ so it follows $f(p) \ne f(q)$. Hence, $(U - \{f(p)\}) \cap f(A) \ne \varnothing$. Thus, $f(p)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$ and $f(p) \in \text{cl}({f(A)})$.

(2) -> (1) I assume the equivalent closed set version of Definition 1. since it's easy to show by taking complements. Let $K$ be a closed in $Y$. We show that $f^{-1}(K)$ is also closed. Let $p$ be a limit point of $f^{-1}(K)$. Then by (2) it follows $f(p) \in \text{cl}(K) = K$. Then $p \in f^{-1}(K)$. Hence, $f^{-1}(K)$ is closed which implies (1).

Thank you!

Comment: As you can see in the [solution-verification tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info), questions that like "Is my proof correct?" are off-topic.

Comment: Oh my bad. I was wondering in particular if I missed something for in my proof (2) -> 1 because it felt a lot simpler than (1) -> (2). Would this be too vague? I don't have anything more specific than that so should I pull the question down?

Comment: I think "why is my proof of (2) $\implies$ (1) much simpler than (1) $\implies$ (2)" is a worthwhile question, but ideally that should be in the question body rather than comments which are in principle ephemeral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof seems correct. The reason (2) $\implies$ (1) looks simpler than the converse is that you use the "easy to show by taking complements" reduction to closed sets in that direction. Using the same reduction, ie assuming $f^{-1}(\text{closed})$ is closed, and supposing $p$ is a limit point of $A$, $f^{-1}(\operatorname{cl}(f(A))$ is a closed set containing $A$ and therefore contains $p$, which is to say $f(p) \in \operatorname{cl}(f(A))$.

Note in general that even if two statements are equivalent, the difficulty of going from one to another need not be symmetric. For an artificial example, if $P \implies Q$ is a "hard to prove" statement, then $P$ is equivalent to "$P \text{ and } Q$", but one of the directions is the same as $P \implies Q$ and the other direction is trivial.